# Switchyard Simple Refrence Exception when get invoked?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jboss, switchyard

I am using switchyard [ I am trying to build simple camel route ],

and what I did is the following :

simple service with camel route that reference another weblogic service [ the problem is when I try to call it using any tool , soap UI for example the error I get is   :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>java.lang.NullPointerException: SWITCHYARD033900: No ServiceReference was found for uri [switchyard://PaltelMobileService]</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

StackTrace :

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: SWITCHYARD033900: No ServiceReference was found for uri [switchyard://PaltelMobileService]
at org.switchyard.component.camel.switchyard.SwitchYardProducer.lookupServiceReference(SwitchYardProducer.java:178) [switchyard-component-camel-switchyard-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
at org.switchyard.component.camel.switchyard.SwitchYardProducer.process(SwitchYardProducer.java:83) [switchyard-component-camel-switchyard-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61) [camel-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:120) [camel-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72) [camel-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398) [camel-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191) [camel-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118) [camel-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80) [camel-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
```

it is highly appreciated if you get back to me as quick as possible

Regards,